# react-select property name for value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have this code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

const optionsExample = [
  {
    code: "CLP",
    country: "CLP",
    minimumAmount: 10000
  },
  {
    code: "USD",
    country: "US",
    minimumAmount: 25000
  }
];

const handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
  console.log("change newValue", newValue); // object changes but it's not selected the right one
};

const CustomControl = () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={optionsExample[0]}
    formatOptionLabel={({ code }) => code}
    options={optionsExample}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(<CustomControl />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

It doesn't work ok because `react-select` expect that the `value` of each object on the data array be named `value`. How can I pass data like in the example? I need that `data` has those properties, I can't change `country` to `value`.

Actually, I used the props `formatOptionLabel` to change the default `label` field from the object to `code` but I don't know how to do the same but for the `value`.

Demo with my code, with the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-formatoptionlabel-forked-deuw1?file=/index.js:0-756

This is working because each object has it's `value` field and that's what is expected by `react-select`

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-formatoptionlabel-forked-d9bdj

Comment: if library api requests a `value` property you should give it. If you really need `country` property what if you duplicate country value to property `value`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't move the mountain, then walk around it.

use inline .map to convert your array of objects

```
const CustomControl = () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={optionsExample[0]}
    formatOptionLabel={({ code }) => code}
    options={optionsExample.map(x => ({ value: x.country, label: x.code })}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
);
```

or better still use useMemo to create a new array, if your array changes

```
const selectOptions = useMemo(() => optionsExample.map(x => ({ value: x.country, label: x.code }),[optionsExample])

  <Select
    defaultValue={selectOptions[0]}
    formatOptionLabel={({ code }) => code}
    options={selectOptions}
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
```